# Can I track to what device an image has been downloaded?

Tags: user-tracking

I want to add a tracking script to my image, but I don't know how to do it. Let's say I have an image of my house which I have stored in an image hosting service. When someone downloads it to their computer or other device, I want to get details about where my image has been downloaded. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow the image to be downloaded directly. Instead, require them to access it via a script, which tracks the request and sends the image data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this in an image. I don't think binary files support any scripting language... you would have to put it on your own server only and write some JavaScript to send information back to you if someone downloaded it, and I don't even think you could get that to work. Hell, you can even download the images that flickr hosts, even though that's why they exist, so you can't do that... you just need $0.02 of web knowledge.

EDIT: No Image hosting site will let you run any custom scripts and I don't think any offer this functionality, your best bet is to host it yourself... or only send it out in e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed script that would run into an image.

You can easily get information about what IP was used to download a file by checking web service logs.

You also can render each image as HTML page that contain the image and run script on that page. (There are plenty of opposite questions here about "why when I get somesite/images/image.jpg I see some strange HTML code").